# how to reduce frame rate of gif using ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, gif, mp4

Currently, I'm reducing the frame rate by converting gif to video by

```
ffmpeg -i asd.gif -vsync 0 -f mp4 -r 10 asd.mp4
```

10 is the frame rate

and then the video to gif by

```
ffmpeg -v warning -i asd.mp4 -vf "fps=8,palettegen" -y palette.png

ffmpeg -v warning -i asd.mp4 -i palette.png -lavfi "fps=8 [x]; [x][1:v] paletteuse" -y asd_r.gif
```

> 8 is the required frame rate
>
> Although this gives gif with a reduced frame rate, it is increasing
>   the size of the resultant gif with the same frame rate of input gif.
>
> So, is there is any better way of reducing the frame rate without
>   increasing the size?